# warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type by 2d pointers in the struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, multidimensional-array

I am new in the C programming and I have researched about in stackoverflow and other website about this warning but they are not the answer of my problem. I have a struct like that:

```
struct threadParams{
    FILE *ptr_myfile;
    FILE *ptr_outputfile;
    int* myArr;
    int height;
    int width;
    int rowStart;
    int colStart;
    int im_height;
    int im_width;
    int** resArr;
    int* windows;
    unsigned char** wholeImage;

};
```

And whenever I have added 2d arrays, resArr and wholeImage, I got this warning in here:

```
pr.resArr=ran;
```

and

```
pr.wholeImage=wholeImage;
```

I have defined pr like that:

```
struct threadParams pr;
```

And these are the places where I initialized ran and wholeImage:

```
int ran[height][width];
unsigned char wholeImage[im_height][im_width];
```

Is there any problem with 2d arrays in the struct? How can i handle that issue?

Thanks

Comment: probably `ran` is not a pointer to a pointer... perhaps you are mixing up arrays with pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please typecast your assignments:

```
pr.wholeImage=(unsigned char **)wholeImage;
pr.resArr=(int **)ran;
```